# How to escape single quotes in Laravels DB::select binding

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel adds single quotes around my orderBy which is causing the query to not execute as expected

I have tried numerous combinations of using DB::raw while trying to remove the single quotes from my select statement and got nowhere.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT cust_name, ad_text, total_sms FROM customers WHERE created_at > :startDate AND created_at < :endDate ORDER BY :orderBy DESC;";

return DB::Select($sql, ['startDate'=>$startDate,'endDate'=>$endDate, 'orderBy' => $orderBy]);?>
```

which comes out to

```
ORDER BY 'total_sms' DESC;
```

How do i escape this binding param so its single quotes are removed?

Comment: You could use some other way to insert the orderBy, do you really need orderBy to be inserted in  the above way.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought i could use bindings instead of string concatenation

Answer (score 3):

Add columns name between " ` " sign, not " ' ".

- To escape single quotes, use: `str_replace("'", "\\'", $str)`

Answer (score 0):

Another good way is

```
  DB::table("customers as c")
  ->whereBetween("created_at",[$start_date, $end_date])
  ->select("cust_name", "ad_text", "total_sms")
  ->orderBy($orderBy,"Desc")
  ->get();
```

Comment: the query is a huge report- this is a stripped down version.